# How to get the average RATE depending on the amount by using excel array formula?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

I have been mixing SUM, IF, SUMIFS but still cant get the result that I needed.
This is one of the array formulas that I have tried:

```
{=(IF(A:A=A8,IF(C:C>0,C:C,0),0)/SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A8,C:C,">0"))*IF(A:A=A8,IF(B:B>0,B:B,0),0)}
```

I need to get the average RATE for 6/18/20 while also factoring how much is the amount on the column 3. Excluding negative values on Column 3. So data that would be needed are the ones on ROWS 16 and 18.

[image: Heres the table]

The value that I'm looking for is **1.6910878023**

This would be the manual way of solving it. 
[ROW 16 RATE: **1.691**, AMOUNT: **123746**] 
[ROW 18 RATE: **1.692**, AMOUNT: **11911**]

=((123746/(123746+11911))*1.691)+((11911/(123746+11911))*1.692)  
=**1.6910878023**

Is this possible? LOL

THANK YOU VERY MUCH GUYS!

Comment: please show in long hand how you would come to that value, ie: `123746/(1.691/123746)+....` or however one would come to the correct answer with the correct values.  I cannot find any version of a formula that comes to your expected output.

Comment: @ScottCraner hi, this would be the manual way of solving it.  
[**ROW 16**  RATE:  1.691,   AMOUNT:    123746]  
[**ROW 18**  RATE:  1.692,   AMOUNT:    11911]  
  
((123746/(123746+11911))*1.691)+((11911/(123746+11911))*1.692)  
= **1.6910878023**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((C14:C20*(C14:C20>0)*(A14:A20=A8))/(SUMIFS(C14:C20,A14:A20,A8,C14:C20,">0")+(B14:B20=0))*(B14:B20)))
```

[image]

Comment: oh wow! Thanks Scott! I have never use `=SUMPRODUCT` and had no idea that it can process arrays. And also this way of filtering `C14:C20*(C14:C20>0)*(A14:A20=A8)` is the first time I've encounter. Thanks!

Comment: btw why what does this do **+(B14:B20=0)**? I tried removing it and still got the result that I needed. _=SUMPRODUCT(((C14:C20*(C14:C20>0)*(A14:A20=A8))/(SUMIFS(C14:C20,A14:A20,A8,C14:C20,">0") **+(B14:B20=0)** )*(B14:B20)))_

Comment: It can probably be removed.

Comment: Another related question how do you exclude a non-numerical so that the formula wont get an error. Because sometime when I have a negative value on column C, i might put sa comments on column B instead of just putting a zero. sometimes on column C too..